# Can't find cygwin setup.exe file?

Tags: svn, cygwin, package

I am trying to add the subversion packet to cygwin and to do this I need to run setup.exe but I can't find it anywhere in my cygwin folder. Where would this be located?

Answer (score 7):

It's not *in* the cygwin folder, it's wherever you left it last time you installed (which may well have been the trash can or a temporary directory). You download it separately since you need it *before* you download/install the packages themselves.

I tend to create a `cyginst` directory into which I put `setup-x86.exe` and then download the entire repository there (without installing). Then I install from local. That way I have a local repository available for other machines without having to download again (it's about 6G so easily fits on most of my USB sticks). And I can always get the local repository updated with setup as needed (it only downloads changes).

The setup executable can be downloaded from the [CygWin site](http://www.cygwin.com/) but keep in mind its name has changed from `setup.exe` - there's now a 32-bit and 64-bit version.