# How To Rebasing Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, rebase

In an desperate attempt I tried to rebase Cygwin using ash.exe in the bin directory
but is said that it will do an full rebase the next time setup.exe is run
where is this file?

Comment: you can find the answer on this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500957/cant-find-cygwin-setup-exe-file

Comment: setup.exe is referring to setup-x86.exe or setup-x86_64.exe that was used to install cygwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I have a problem also as yours, I tried to rebaseall but it did not work from /cygwin/bin BUT I tried this:
/cygwin/bin/rebase-trigger full
then close all cygwin shells (or even reboot your windows), then start cygwin installer again, go to next until the end of the installer, then it will run a rebase for your installed packages.
This solved my problem

Comment: how did you run the command? I see the file `rebase-trigger` but it's not executable

Comment: @SaifMasadeh The answer that I've provided is since 2017, I don't know now if something is changed, and I'm now using mac operating system, not windows

Comment: It seems that windows setup is not an easy task.

Comment: @SaifMasadeh I don't know if this can help, but just to mention it here: instead of using cygwin, there is a windows subsystem for linux https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10 or to install linux as virtual machine if it is possible if you have some programs that need linux